# Prevent duplicate request in rest api

Tags: php, android, ios, rest

I am making rest API for android app in 'PHP'. I come up with an issue that when say user register API hits then it creates a duplicate entry of record send in request data. I checked it in postman there its working fine. Maybe this issue comes from an app but I want to know that how to prevent this on server -side. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `udpateOrCreate` method if you want to store some records. 
you can check if there is no record of that data then create it but if all inputs match the ones which are created seconds before then update it.
 Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to have some unique information about the registering user like username or email address. Before inserting the entry of a user in the database, check if the username or email already exists or not. If it exists the show an error response saying username or email already exists in your database and ask the user to use another email or username or try login/forgot password with the one he is using.